# Slideshow's animation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, vue.js

In this Vue component, I tried to make a slideshow.

The logic works this way:

1) Making an array of all sources of pictures I want to put in(array: pictures)

2) Set a `variable(Count)` to 0, so that it starts from the start.

3) Putting `v-bind:src="pictures[count]"` on an `img` tag so that it changes the source by the variable(count)

4) Putting functions on 2 buttons that returns in images or goes forward in images.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img v-bind:src="pictures[count]" alt="">
    <button @click="Switching(1)">Forward</button>
    <button @click="Switching(-1)">Back</button>
    <p>{{this.count + 1}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
      pictures: [
        "http://www.hotel-bb.com/image.htm?id=93652",
        "https://s-ec.bstatic.com/images/hotel/max1280x900/681/68184730.jpg",
        "https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_picture_of_the_beautiful_natural_scenery_03_166249.jpg",
        "https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/the_beach_at_dusk_couple_of_picture_165871.jpg"
      ],
      stop: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    Switching: function(n) {
      this.count += n;
      if (this.count > this.pictures.length - 1) {
        this.count = 0;
      } else if (this.count < 0) {
        this.count = this.pictures.length - 1;
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
img {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
}
</style>
```

It works properly. The problem is that when I put an animation on it, it doesn't work except for the first picture that loads, when I switch by the two buttons, the pictures don't get animated.

I tried `transition: 0.5s`, `animation` and `Keyframes` and nothing works. I'm guessing that it is because the pictures don't appear but they get loaded and src gets changed. How I can make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For building a slideshow on Vue JS, I suggest [Vueper Slides](https://antoniandre.github.io/vueper-slides/#examples). It will do all that for you.

Unless it is for a learning purpose.